# Does a method of a class should have at least one parameter referring to an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python In a Nutshell says that:

> a method defined  in  a  class  body  has  a  mandatory  first 
>   parameter,  conventionally  named self , that refers to the instance
>   on which you call the method.

Does a method of a class should have at least one parameter referring to an instance?

Is it a bad practice to create a method without any parameter?

Is it a good practice to always make a method work when calling it on either the class or an instance of the class?

Note that I am not talking about a static method or class method, but an ordinary method.

```
>>> class C5(object):
...     def hello():
...         print('Hello')
... 
>>> C5.hello()
Hello
>>> C5().hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: hello() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `def hello()` by `def hello(self)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709832/3926995) for more informations about `self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always put `self` as the first parameter in the class method. If you want call class method without creating a class instance, need to write following:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("Hi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python wants you to pass self as an argument into your class methods so that python knows that the methods belong to the class that they are in.